# kendo aspnetmvc post error conflict with Jquery json read

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, kendo-grid

I am using Jquery 2.0.3 and kendu.aspnetmvc and getting below error while loading more than 2900 records in ajax post

```
Error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Kendo post call

```
.Read(read => read.Action("VolumeSearchRead", "VolumeSearch").Data("Searchdata"))
```

Controller return

```
return Json(volumesearchViewModel.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

working when I do this

```
   //if (volumesearchViewModel.Count > 2900)
            //{
            //    firsthalf = volumesearchViewModel;
            //    volumesearchViewModel.RemoveRange(2900, volumesearchViewModel.Count - 2900);
            //}
```

Comment: you could be hitting the max limit of your return request string for your site if it is happening at a specific number. have you looked at what the 500 error is actually sending back in the browser dev console? If it is the limit for a json request then you will need to increase the allowed size for your website. The other question is why load so much data into the front end this would seem more suitable for server paging, filtering etc.

Comment: Thanks your support, Yes you're exactly right, we can use Server paging but I have Excel export function in View. If i'm using Server page(page size =500) then i can able to download excel with 500 rows of records. but i want to download all record which i have search condition(3200 records).  In this case serve paging but difficult. Could you please suggest some other way to achive excel download .